# Effect of SELECT ... FOR UPDATE for parallel select statements

Tags: php, mysql

(Please excuse my english in advance since I'm from Switzerland and English is not my mother tongue.)

I think I have read about every related topic here on what I am going to explain now, but couldn't find a satisfying answer to my following question/situation.

In a MySQL table (innoDB) I have many users, identified by a unique user_id.

I want to call an external API for every user at most every 60 seconds, since the API does not allow more than one request per user per minute.

Therefore, i have the column last_api_call int(12) containing PHP's time().

Now via ajax and/or cronjobs, I make an API call for the user who has been waiting the longest for his API call:

```
> select * from users where last_api_call<time()-60seconds order by last_api_call asc limit 1

> update users set last_api_call=time() where user_id=user_id_from_above_statement
```

Now session1 gets a user_id and before session1 updates the last_api_call, session2 might get the same user_id and there I violate the API rules by sending two requests for the same user just after another.

After reading through all the related topics here, I come to the conclusion that "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" solves my problem:

```
session1> > select * from users where last_api_call<time()-60seconds order by last_api_call asc limit 1 FOR UPDATE
```

Question: What happens now to session2? Does it just get the very next record, or does it "wait" until session1 releases the record? It should not get the same record, since "last_api_call-60()" does not mach anymore, so it should just use the next row in line?!

In other words, is the row1 locked through "select ... for update"  just "invisible" for session2 or does it wait for the same row1 to be unlocked, just to see that the same row1 does not match the main where clause anymore and now row is handled at all?